# Rounding Error in Texture Creation? -Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, rounding-error

I am creating a simple 2D tile game. To approach the task of creating lots of tiles at runtime I have decided to create a mesh and apply a texture created procedurally over top. To accomplish this I have a reference tileMap which contains every sort of tile. I then assign the UVs to the map. This method works fairly well but a gap appears between certain tiles. Any idea why?
Below I inserted 2 functions, buildTexture is creating the texture itself and chopTileMap returns a 2D array with Vector2s which are unique to each tile. This array can then be used such that the array of Vector2s and index 0 will return the 4 coordinates of the bottom left tile in my tile map.

```
void buildTexture()
{
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    Vector2[][] tileMap = chopTileMap();
    List<Vector2> uvList = new List<Vector2>();
    mesh.GetUVs(0, uvList);
    Vector2[] uvs = uvList.ToArray();

    //To set a UV it has to be given the fraction regarding to the tile map out of 1 (for a tile map 3 wide the vectors would be  0,1/2,2/3,1)
    //tileMap is set as tileMap[tileID(index)][Point on tile (0-3)]
    //for each UV, assign the set of 4 to points on the tile map

    for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < colCount; c++)
        {
            //int tileIndex = Random.Range(0, tileMap.Length-1);
            int tileIndex = Random.Range(0,4);
            uvs[((r * colCount + c) * 4) + 0] = tileMap[tileIndex][0];
            uvs[((r * colCount + c) * 4) + 1] = tileMap[tileIndex][1];
            uvs[((r * colCount + c) * 4) + 2] = tileMap[tileIndex][2];
            uvs[((r * colCount + c) * 4) + 3] = tileMap[tileIndex][3];
        }
    }

    textureMap.Apply();
    mesh.uv = uvs;
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    meshRenderer.materials[0].mainTexture = textureMap;
}

Vector2[][] chopTileMap()
{
    int numColsOfMap = textureMap.width / tileResolution;
    int numRowsOfMap = textureMap.height / tileResolution;
    Vector2[][] tiles = new Vector2[numColsOfMap * numRowsOfMap][];

    for (int r = 0; r < numRowsOfMap; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < numColsOfMap; c++){
            tiles[r * numColsOfMap + c] = new Vector2[4];
            tiles[r * numColsOfMap + c][0] = new Vector2((float)(c) / numColsOfMap, (float)(r) / numRowsOfMap);
            tiles[r * numColsOfMap + c][1] = new Vector2((float)(c+1) / numColsOfMap, (float)(r) / numRowsOfMap);
            tiles[r * numColsOfMap + c][2] = new Vector2((float)(c) / numColsOfMap, (float)(r+1) / numRowsOfMap);
            tiles[r * numColsOfMap + c][3] = new Vector2((float)(c+1) / numColsOfMap, (float)(r+1) / numRowsOfMap);
        }
    }

    return tiles;
}
```

In this picture thin blue lines can be seen between the tiles which is the background coming through.

[image]

The amount off by is less than a pixel as noted when trying to adjust the UV to compensate for this and as a result is hard to see but is defintly noticeable at runtime. The most predominant line in the image below is the thin blue one running vertically next to the player on the left.

Comment: tbh there is gap between most of them, just some are much bigger.. is numcolsofmap coming out as an integer? I would have thought you wanted an integer divide, and then +1 if there was remainder.

Comment: just another question: `textureMap.Apply();` .. but before I see no point where you would change `textureMap` so what is the `Apply` for?

Comment: @BugFinder, Yes numColsOfMap is an integer and it always should be. The texture map in this case is 256*64 and the tileResolution is 64.

Comment: @derHugo That is my bad, this method originally created a new texture pixel by pixel so had to reapply the texture. Now only the UVs are being updated so this is unnecessary